# Vaadin, Switching Content via setContent() not displaying

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

Vaadin 7.6.2

Take the following example:

```
import com.vaadin.ui.Button;
import com.vaadin.ui.Button.ClickListener;
import com.vaadin.ui.HorizontalLayout;
import com.vaadin.ui.Panel;
import com.vaadin.ui.TextField;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;

public class MyClass extends Panel {

    TextField        myField  = new TextField();
    HorizontalLayout hLayout  = new HorizontalLayout( myField );
    VerticalLayout   vLayout  = new VerticalLayout( myField );    
    Button           button   = new Button( "Press Me" );

    public MyClass() {
        super();
        applySettings();
    }

    private void applySettings() {
        button.addClickListener(new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void buttonClick(Button.ClickEvent event) {
                setContent( hLayout );
            }
        });

        vLayout.addComponent( button );


        this.setContent( vLayout );
    }
}
```

When I click the button the **vLayout** disappears but the **hLayout** (with `myField`) doesn't appear.  What step am I'm missing?  Or, is there a different way to do this?

If I add a secondary text field, like so:

```
TextField        myField  = new TextField();
TextField        myField2 = new TextField();  // tf2
HorizontalLayout hLayout  = new HorizontalLayout( myField );
VerticalLayout   vLayout  = new VerticalLayout( myField2 );  // tf2
```

It appears to work, however what I'm trying to achieve is the ability to dynamically switch my layouts using the fields (and their data) from the switched-out layout.

Comment: Can you post a full example, also known as [SSCCE or Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: @Morfic updated the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One component can not have 2 parents at the same time (`hLayout` & `vLayout` in your case), thus if it already has one, Vaadin will remove it from the previous parent and add it as a child to the current one. This is the `addComponent` method inherited from [AbstractComponentContainer](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin/blob/master/server/src/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractComponentContainer.java):

```java
/**
 * This only implements the events and component parent calls. The extending
 * classes must implement component list maintenance and call this method
 * after component list maintenance.
 * 
 * @see com.vaadin.ui.ComponentContainer#addComponent(Component)
 */
@Override
public void addComponent(Component c) {
    // Make sure we're not adding the component inside it's own content
    if (isOrHasAncestor(c)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Component cannot be added inside it's own content");
    }

    if (c.getParent() != null) {
        // If the component already has a parent, try to remove it
        AbstractSingleComponentContainer.removeFromParent(c);
    }

    c.setParent(this);
    fireComponentAttachEvent(c);
    markAsDirty();
}
```

If you're in [debug mode](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/advanced/advanced-debug.html), you can somewhat see an image of the composition tree in your browser by adding `?debug` to your URL, something like http://localhost:8080/?debug

[image: component hierarchy]

Answer (score 1):

Well, it looks like I may have solved it.

```
import com.vaadin.ui.Button;
import com.vaadin.ui.Button.ClickListener;
import com.vaadin.ui.HorizontalLayout;
import com.vaadin.ui.Panel;
import com.vaadin.ui.TextField;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;

public class MyClass extends Panel {

    TextField        myField  = new TextField();
    HorizontalLayout hLayout  = new HorizontalLayout();
    VerticalLayout   vLayout  = new VerticalLayout();    
    Button           button   = new Button( "Press Me" );

    public MyClass() {
        super();
        applySettings();
    }

    private void applySettings() {
        button.addClickListener(new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void buttonClick(Button.ClickEvent event) {
                vLayout.removeAllComponents();   // this is optional
                hLayout.addComponent( myField );
                setContent( hLayout );
            }
        });

        vLayout.addComponents( myField, button );

        this.setContent( vLayout );
    }
}
```

If I don't add `myField` in the layout constructors, but add it later in the code, it seems to work.

**UPDATE**

After more testing it seems whichever layout LAST called `addComponent()` for a given field, THAT layout gets the handle to that field.  This behavior seems odd and if someone could explain why this is? That would be enlightening.

Comment: You are correct, Vaadin _shifts_ from one parent to the other when assigning a component to multiple parents, because a component can only have at most 1 parent at any time (it may have none when it's been just constructed). It's just like a tree structure. See my answer for a more detailed explanation. Anyway +1 for figuring out it yourself :-)

Comment: Just a small update for when you have the time, I didn't know if you knew about [debug mode](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/advanced/advanced-debug.html) so I updated the answer with a few details and a small screenshot. Cheers